# Result format of Vespa Query

Tags: embedding, vespa, vector-database, semantic-search

I want to see the output of the query as "Track id" and "Title" but I am only able to see the metadata as attached. What changes do I need to make in the results to get desired output?
[image]

Expected Output- "Track id" and "Title"
What changes do I need to make in the results to get desired output?

Answer (score 1):

`totalCount:0` indicates this is an empty result set - please try with a query like `'select * from track where true'` to hit all documents to get results, and refine the query from there.

https://docs.vespa.ai/en/nearest-neighbor-search-guide.html#exact-nearest-neighbor-search is an example of something similar to what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for an empty index. You can see this from the `coverage` element where `documents = 0`